# Installing default MySQL Tables in Windows (mysql_install_db)

Tags: mysql, windows, installation

In Linux, the default MySQL grant tables can be created with the `mysql_install_db` script, but that does not work on Windows.

How can the default grant tables be installed on Windows?

(No, I’m not looking for the response that Google’s results are packed full of about how they are automatically installed on Windows, because that is only the case with the installer distribution, not the ZIP package. Besides, that does not help after MySQL is installed and the data directory is damaged or is being replaced or such.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I knew I had faced this before and managed to figure it out, so I searched my drives and found a batch file I had written last time.

For anyone else who experiences this issue, what you need to do is to run the server daemon with the `--bootstrap` parameters.

Here is the script I used to dump all the databases out to an SQL file and re-import them (that is, manually—and inconveniently—implementing a MySQL counterpart to SQLite’s `vacuum` command).

```
::Start the server, change to the MySQL bin directory, and dump all databases
net start MySQL
cd       /d "%serverdir%\MySQL\bin"
mysqldump  -uroot -p --all-tablespaces --all-databases --add-drop-database --add-drop-table --add-locks --comments --complete-insert --compress --create-options --events --routines --quick --quote-names --set-charset --triggers > %temp%\all.sql

::Stop the server and rename the data directory (as backup)
net stop mysql
ren         "%datadir%\MySQL"        MySQL_

::Delete data folder in MySQL directory, optionally copy old mysql tables
rd    /s /q "%serverdir%\MySQL\data"
md          "%serverdir%\MySQL\data"
xcopy /s /e "%datadir%\MySQL_\mysql" "%serverdir%\MySQL\data"

::Bootstrap the server (creates grant tables if they don’t exist)
mysqld --bootstrap

::Run server, optionally upgrade tables and move upgrade log to data directory
start mysqld --skip-grant-tables
mysql_upgrade --force
move "%serverdir%\MySQL\bin\mysql_upgrade_info" "%serverdir%\MySQL\data"

::Import all databases, shutdown, delete logs, then move to old data dir
mysql      -uroot -p < %temp%\all.sql
mysqladmin -uroot -p shutdown
md  "%datadir%\MySQL"
del "%serverdir%\MySQL\data\ib_logfile?"
xcopy /s /e "%serverdir%\MySQL\data\*" "%datadir%\MySQL"
rd    /s /q "%serverdir%\MySQL\data"

::Start the server, if it works, then all should be well, so del
net start mysql
rd    /s /q "%datadir%\MySQL_"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have had this strange dilemma in MySQL grant tables for Windows, I recommend the following:

Step 1. Get the ZIP FIle distribution that does not have the installer in it.

Step 2. Unzip it's contents to `C:\MySQLZipStuff`

Step 3. Look for the folder `C:\MySQLZipStuff\data\mysql`

Step 4. Copy all the files in `C:\MySQLZipStuff\data\mysql` over to the mysql folder of your desired data directory.

Step 5. `net start mysql`

If you have the mysql folder already you can do this instead:

Step 1. Edit `my.ini` by adding this line in the [mysqld] section

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
skip-networking
```

Step 2. `net stop mysql`

Step 3. `net start mysql`

At this point, you can just type 'mysql' and you are in. However, you cannot run GRANT commands with grant tables disabled.

Step 4. You will have to enter one superuser manually. Like this

a) `INSERT INTO mysql.user SET user='root',host='localhost';`

b) `SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost'\G`

This will show all the columns in the user table. You will have to manually change each column like this:

UPDATE mysql.user SET select_priv='Y',insert_priv='Y',... WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost';

c) Setup a password for root@localhost like this:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=PASSWORD('whateverpasswordyouwant')
WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost';
```

Step 5. Remove `skip-grant-tables` and `skip-networking` from `my.ini`

Step 6. `net stop mysql`

Step 7. `net start mysql`

Now you can log into mysql as root using 'whateverpasswordyouwant' as the password.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks for the tips; that’s a lot of steps considering on Linux it only takes a single script. `:-(`

Answer (score 3):

FYI,

it's `--initialize` now, instead of the deprecated `--bootstrap`

---

NB. for the sake of completeness:

To run this on using an unprivileged account:

```
mysqld.exe --log_syslog=0 --console --standalone --initialize
```

Then start the server:

```
mysqld.exe   --log_syslog=0 --console --standalone
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who uses XAMPP and experiences this problem, XAMPP ships with a backup of these default mysql tables.

Copy everything in this folder `C:\xampp\mysql\backup\mysql` and paste it in `C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql`, overwriting everything.

Be warned: data may be lost--I wouldn't know, I had a clean install.

Comment: That’s handy for XAMPP, but it’s a pretty limited use-case scenario since MySQL is a lot more general-purpose than just a single web-server.

Comment: Oh, I know. I just wanted to post that there for anyone who landed on this page after Googling for that error and also uses XAMPP (like me). I don't expect this to be marked as accepted, but to be left as reference for others.

Comment: Okay cool. I didn’t realize having to manually reset XAMPP was a common problem.

Comment: It isn't, I have no clue how this happened and I didn't want to rerun the installer for fear of overwriting carefully manicured configuration files :P

Comment: Oh I know! Since MySQL has no built-in method of shrinking the database file (like the `vacuum` command of SQLite3, et. al.), I have to manually dump it and create a new one now and then since I don’t have a lot space; but I’m always worried about doing so, so I put it off as long as possible.