# Should I exclude mysql database from multi master replication?

Tags: mysql, replication

Running mysql in a two master replication setup. There are many databases and they are all replicating correctly including the mysql database itself.

Is it safe to replicate mysql or should I exclude it via the my.cnf ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `mysql` schema is usually manipulated with [**GRANT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) and [**REVOKE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/revoke.html) commands, there is no need to let the `mysql` schema replicate. Why ?

Someone could hack privileges in by means of INSERT commands into `mysql.user`.

Such hacks are possible because I wrote about it before

- `Oct 28, 2011` : [MySQL: trying to create root user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7364/mysql-trying-to-create-root-user/7368#7368)
- `Sep 12, 2011` : [How do you gain access to embedded MySQL database via localhost command line?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5677/how-do-you-gain-access-to-embedded-mysql-database-via-localhost-command-line/5679#5679)
- `Mar 06, 2011` : [Installing default MySQL Tables in Windows (mysql_install_db)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1592/installing-default-mysql-tables-in-windows-mysql-install-db/1597#1597)

If these hacks were done on a Master, a Slave might intercept them. The new grants on the Slave would not be active until someone restarted mysqld on the Slave or ran `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` on the Slave.

So, to answer your question: `exclude it via the my.cnf`